# bat file creates a "corrupt" zip

Tags: batch-file

I created a build.bat file to zip up the correct files for my browser extension and makes Firefox and Chromium builds. The problem is that, for some reason, these zips seem to be corrupt in some way.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define variables
set ZIP_NAME_FIREFOX=Firefox.zip
set ZIP_NAME_CHROMIUM=Chromium.zip
set SOURCE_FOLDER=%CD%
set TEMP_FOLDER=%SOURCE_FOLDER%\temp

:: Ensure the temp folder is clean
if exist "%TEMP_FOLDER%" rmdir /s /q "%TEMP_FOLDER%"
mkdir "%TEMP_FOLDER%"

:: Copy files and folders individually to avoid cyclic copy
echo Copying files to the temp directory...
xcopy "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\mrbeastify.js" "%TEMP_FOLDER%" /Q
xcopy "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\manifest v3.json" "%TEMP_FOLDER%" /Q
xcopy "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\images" "%TEMP_FOLDER%\images\" /E /Q
xcopy "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\icons" "%TEMP_FOLDER%\icons\" /E /Q

echo Creating Firefox zip folder...
powershell Compress-Archive -Path "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\mrbeastify.js", "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\manifest.json", "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\images", "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\icons" -DestinationPath "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\%ZIP_NAME_FIREFOX%" -Force
echo Firefox zip folder created successfully.

:: Rename manifest for Chromium
echo Preparing files for Chromium zip...
rename "%TEMP_FOLDER%\manifest v3.json" "manifest.json"

echo Creating Chromium zip folder...
powershell Compress-Archive -Path "%TEMP_FOLDER%\mrbeastify.js", "%TEMP_FOLDER%\manifest.json", "%TEMP_FOLDER%\images", "%TEMP_FOLDER%\icons" -DestinationPath "%SOURCE_FOLDER%\%ZIP_NAME_CHROMIUM%" -Force
echo Chromium zip folder created successfully.

:: Cleanup
if exist "%TEMP_FOLDER%" rmdir /s /q "%TEMP_FOLDER%"

echo All operations completed successfully.
pause
```

When I zip the files manually, it works fine. I can load the extension temporarily and nothing goes wrong. When I use the build.bat file, and load the extension, my script cannot locate any of the images in the folders, and the extension icons also don't load.

I then decided to see what was up with the images, so I tried to delete the images folder *inside the zip* and replace it with a version known to work. Windows actually *wasn't able to delete these folders* (Luckily 7zip could). When I finally copied in the images and icons folders in manually, it all works.

What on earth could be going wrong here? I already checked whether the file was locked by some program (it wasn't), and whether running cmd as admin works (it doesn't).

Comment: I could, but I want this to be accessible to other people as well, some of which might not have 7zip. It's a last resort I guess.

Comment: The firefox creation command uses another file called manifest.json that is also present in the folder. Firefox doesn't (to my knowledge) support manifest v3. That file is only there for the chrome version. 

I only compress those select files because there are other files in the directory that I do not want included in every version. I do not want manifest V3 in the Firefox file, and I don't want the original manifest.json in the Chromium file.

In the end the logistics of the manifest.json file don't really matter. I'm just very curious why the resulting zip file doesn't work as intended

Comment: I create a temp directory, copy the icons, images, manifest V3 and the js file in there. I then zip the icons, images, manifest.json and the js file (which are present in the source folder), after which I zip all the files in the temp folder. I'll give you a link to [my repository](https://github.com/MagicJinn/MrBeastify-Youtube) so you can see the file structure and try the bat file. Again, which files get archived doesn't really matter. The code creates 2 zip files, and all files seem to be present. I'm worried about is why the zip file is so buggy, and why Firefox can't load the images.

Comment: Regardless of the above, you need to clarify whether the content of the archive, extracts to perfect copies of the original source, rather than your created archive being incompatible as an extension in your particular browser(s).

Comment: Unpacked, they are byte for byte exactly the same. When archived there are some minor binary differences. In the meantime I tested the Chromium version in Chrome, and I get the same error. Something weird is happening here. I might try some more investigation but I guess I'll use 7zip for now. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: What do you mean lack of content. The code creates 2 zip files. You can check it's content. It's there. I can open the zip files, see all the images, extract it, and it's all intact.

Comment: The problem you are describing is not a programming one. It is either with your choice of compression tool and/or its configuration, or less likely, the browser requires an archive with more, or less, files inside; or the contents of one or more of those files is not compatible as an extension. A better alternative would be to create the archives yourself manually, which you stated works, test them, and make those available instead of expecting your targets to build them themselves.

Comment: I'm now doing it with 7zip. I was just very confused as to why the Compress-Archive instructions screws up images for some reason, while compressing them manually doesn't.

Comment: Compress-Archive isn't screwing up anything! You've already proven that the extratced files are byte for byte copies. The issue is clearly that the type or archives created using that particular cmdlet with its default settings on your machine, is not fully compatible as extensions for your particular web browsers.

Comment: Well I already noted that for some reason windows also has trouble with editing the zip file:

so I tried to delete the images folder inside the zip and replace it with a version known to work. Windows actually wasn't able to delete these folders (<from the original post)

Comment: If the files can be extraced to byte by byte copies, then the cmdlet has done its job. The rest of it does not matter, because, there is no programming code issue here.